# slideToggle not working when parent link is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I have a list of links in a footer then when you click on the titles along the bottom a panel for each on slides up with links in.

If one panel is open and I click another link along the footer, the open panel closes and the link in the footer that was just clicked expands.

If I click a link in the footer, the panel slides up, however, if re-click the same link in the footer to close the panel it slides down and back up again.

Any thoughts?

Here's the code and jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/88no8eay/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Header</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/new_build/bootstrapgrid/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/new_build/bootstrapgrid/css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <footer style="position:absolute; bottom:0px;">
        <ul id="footer_menu">
            <li id="ftr_information" class="ftr_section col-md-2">
                <span class="ftr_ttl">Title 1 <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></span>
                <ul class="footer_sublist">
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="ftr_gifts" class="ftr_section col-md-2">
                <span class="ftr_ttl">Title 2 <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></span>
                <ul class="footer_sublist">
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="ftr_birthday" class="ftr_section col-md-2">
                <span class="ftr_ttl">Title 3 <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></span>
                <ul class="footer_sublist">
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="ftr_seasonal" class="ftr_section col-md-2">
                <span class="ftr_ttl">Title 4 <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></span>
                <ul class="footer_sublist">
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="ftr_occasion" class="ftr_section col-md-2">
                <span class="ftr_ttl">Title 5<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></span>
                <ul class="footer_sublist">
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1 &#187;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ftr_section .ftr_ttl').click(function () {
    $('.footer_sublist').slideUp();         
    $(this).closest(".ftr_section").find("ul").slideToggle({direction:"up"}, 300);          
    $(this).closest(".ftr_section").find(".fa-chevron-down, .fa-chevron-up").toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
});         
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/88no8eay/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to achieve this, I choose to put a gating class `on` or whatever name you choose for it. All it does is to tell you if the menu is open or not

```
$('.ftr_section .ftr_ttl').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $('.footer_sublist').slideUp();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).closest(".ftr_section").find("ul").slideToggle({
        direction: "up"
    }, 300);
    $(this).closest(".ftr_section").find(".fa-chevron-down, .fa-chevron-up").toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88no8eay/2/

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but this works for me

```
if($(this).closest(".ftr_section").find("ul").is(":hidden")){
    $('.footer_sublist').slideUp();                 
}
```